# Ruby on Rails : check whether internet connection in on or off?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Let us take a few line of code from controller as:

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @vendor = Vendor.new
  end

  def create
    @vendor = Vendor.new(params[:vendor])
    if @vendor.save
      VendorMailer.registration_confirmation(@vendor).deliver
      flash[:success] = "Vendor Added Successfully"
      redirect_to amain_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Now, in the `localhost` when my connection in `off` it show me error of `socket error` (as expected) but if i make a condition :

```
 def create
   @vendor = Vendor.new(params[:vendor])
   if @vendor.save
     if (internet is connected )
       flash[:success] = "Vendor Added Successfully mail have been send"
       VendorMailer.registration_confirmation(@vendor).deliver
       redirect_to amain_path
     else
       flash[:success] = "Vendor Added Successfully mail is not send"
       redirect_to amain_path
     end
   else
     render 'new'
   end
 end
```

I t would be kind if you help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fancy that you check for a connection. As you said, when there is no connection to rails and the remote mail server (or dns) rails throws an exception. So you should catch that exception and handle it accordingly.

```
def create
  @vendor = Vendor.new(params[:vendor])
  if @vendor.save
    begin
      VendorMailer.registration_confirmation(@vendor).deliver
      flash[:success] = "Vendor Added Successfully"
      redirect_to amain_path
    rescue SocketError => e
      flash[:success] = "Vendor Added Successfully mail is not send"
      redirect_to amain_path
    end
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: @SNEHPANDYA You mentioned `SocketError` so that's one. In that piece of code not many things can go wrong so catching everything is a solid idea. what you can do is rescue all errors and log them to get your cases.